# Boost graph libraries: setting edge weight values

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I am investigating the use of the boost graph libraries in order to apply them to various network problems I have in mind.

In the examples I have been looking at the graph edge values ("weights") are always initialized as integers, such as in these [Bellman-Ford](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/example/bellman-example.cpp) and [Kruskal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/example/kruskal-example.cpp) algorithms eg:

```
int weights[] = { 1, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1 };
```

My problem is if I try and change the weights to double, I get a heap of warning messages about conversions etc, which so far I have not been able to figure out how to overcome.

Does anyone see a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's caused by a mismatch between the `weights[]` array and the type used for edge weights by your boost graph/algorithm.

In the first linked sample, eg, you should also change

```
struct EdgeProperties {
  int weight;
};
[...]
property_map<Graph, int EdgeProperties::*>::type
```

to

```
struct EdgeProperties {
  double weight;
};
[...]
property_map<Graph, double EdgeProperties::*>::type
```

In the second

```
typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, undirectedS,
    no_property, property < edge_weight_t, int > > Graph;
```

to

```
typedef adjacency_list < vecS, vecS, undirectedS,
    no_property, property < edge_weight_t, double > > Graph;
```

Comment: Hi the code can be seen in those links: bellman-example.cpp and kruskal-example.cpp

Comment: Your suggestion for the second (Kruskal) has worked, cheers. I cannot quite get over the Bellman hurdle yet.

Comment: In the bellman example you also need to change the type of the property map for the edges. Bundled properties are my favorite way to use the BGL (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html).